# If Function and cin

Tags: c++, if-statement, boolean

Im very new to c++ and trying to write a simple game to learn some of the basic mechanics and i'm having trouble with my code,

How do I define the function WantToPlay so that when a player enters "yes" it replies fantastic, and "no" replies boooo?

My current code gives the error that WantToPlay must be of bool type, but i'm not sure how to use a boolean function to rectify it?

Thanks!

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;


string leader;
string WantToPlay;

int main()
 {
    std::cout << "Dungeon Master: Welcome to my dungeon, traveller! What is         your name?" << std::endl;
cin >> leader;
cout << "Dungeon Master: Well hello, " << leader << " I have a little quest for you if you're interested?" << endl;
cout << "(Please enter ""yes"" or ""no"")" << endl;


cin >> WantToPlay;

if (WantToPlay = "yes")
    cout << "Fantastic!" << endl;
else if (WantToPlay = "no")
    cout << "boooo" << endl;




return 0;


}
```

Comment: `WantToPlay = "yes"` -> `WantToPlay == "yes"`

Comment: Enable more compiler warning.

Answer (score 2):

you need use the o̶p̶e̶r̶a̶t̶o̶r̶ c̶o̶m̶p̶a̶r̶a̶t̶o̶r̶  equality operator. "=="
What you are doing is assigning, not comparing.

Comment: This thing is called "equality operator". A comparator is [something different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

(WantToPlay = "Yes") means **assigning** the string value "Yes" to the string variable WantToPlay

Since you are comparing the value of the variable with "Yes", you should use "==", because (WantToPlay == "Yes") means the string value "Yes" is the **same** as the value in string variable WantToPlay.

Answer (score -1):

Did you know the difference between "=" and "==" ? Check your if statement, and correct it.
Tip: you can't use assignment in if condition.

Comment: Well, you _can_ use assignment in if condition, but it doesn't give the same result as equality test.

Comment: imho low quality, because it should be answer but is a question + wrong statement

Comment: yes, but assignment in if condition won't return any bool value that if can recognize :) but in big summary problem in this case is using "=" instead of "=="

Comment: many things can be converted to bool, otherwise using `=` in conditions wouldnt be such a common error. You can use assignment in conditions, but 99% of the time this is not what you want.